# Java : add integers using StringTokenizer

Tags: java

I want to read the data from an "DataFile.txt" file, but in a program I have 2 integers, so how can I pass integers ("days" and "tprice" variables are supposed to be integers) using StringTokenizer?

```
 private void readDataFileAndDisplay()
      {    
           String allRecord="";     // all details of customer    
           try
           {
                Scanner in = new Scanner (new FileReader ("DataFile.txt")); //open file    
                String myEntry = "" ;   
                String name ="";
                String ID="";
                String roomType ="";
                String meal="";
                String days="";
                String tprice="";  

                while (in.hasNextLine ())
                {    
                    myEntry = in.nextLine();
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (myEntry, ",");
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens ())
                    {    
                        name = st.nextToken();
                        ID = st.nextToken();
                        name = st.nextToken();
                        roomType = st.nextToken();
                        meal = st.nextToken();
                        days = st.nextToken();
                        tprice =st.nextToken();
                        myList.add (new Customer (name, ID, roomType, meal, days, tprice));
                    }    
                } // end of while loop
                in.close(); // close file
              } catch (IOException ex)
              {
                     System.out.println ("file loading failed.");
              }
   }
```

I have also tried parseInt like:

```
int Intdays = Integer.parseInt (st.nextToken ());
int IntTprice = Integer.parseInt (st.nextToken ());
```

but after compiling it is showing the exception below:
[image]

Comment: Can't see the error (broken image) but it does look like your `hasMoreTokens()` logic needs a bit of thinking. Will you have more than one record per line? Perhaps provide some sample data?

Comment: i think there are spaces between numbers???

Comment: Problem is not with Intger or String. Your loop for tokens is faulty. You checking

Comment: This is the one line record in my text file.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = st.nextToken();
                    ID = st.nextToken();
                    name = st.nextToken();
                    roomType = st.nextToken();
                    meal = st.nextToken();
                    days = st.nextToken();
                    tprice =st.nextToken();
                    int Intdays = Integer.parseInt(days);
                    int IntTprice = Integer.parseInt(tprice);
                 myList.add(new Customer(name,ID,roomType,meal,Intdays,IntTprice));
```

Try with this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
days   = Integer.parseInt (st.nextToken ());
tprice = Integer.parseInt (st.nextToken ());
```

would do it, if you declare days and tprice as int.

But you can use your Scanner directly - I show how to with a String instead of a file, which is better for demonstration:

```
data = "John, Miller, 303, 404";
sc = new java.util.Scanner (data);
sc.useDelimiter (", ");
name = sc.next ();      // John
surname = sc.next ();   // Miller
tdays = sc.nextInt ();  // 303
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read name twice. Your data has only 6 fields where as you are trying to read 7 fields. (name = st.nextToken() looks like a typo)

```
 while (st.hasMoreTokens ())
                {    
                    name = st.nextToken();
                    ID = st.nextToken();
                    name = st.nextToken();
                    roomType = st.nextToken();
                    meal = st.nextToken();
                    days = st.nextToken();
                    tprice =st.nextToken();
                    myList.add (new Customer (name, ID, roomType, meal, days, tprice));
                }
```

this is wrong. You  need to check for st.hasMoreTokens() every time before you call st.nextToken().